# How do you connect inferred Parameters to the the types used to call a TypeScript function

Tags: typescript

TL;DR - How do I remove the error in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYwLwwN4FgBQMbQBOATGAK4C2AFAPpyEDmAXAVIUmAwJSYyECmUMoTAwALMQDcMAL4AaXPnIViRWvWYxlAI36EeGPoOGiA5ADMQhKAE8AtFADuIU9Pm4Zk3LlsJ+MAEEABQBJNBhffhBzeGQvHEjA0IAxMjBgADk4Cn90AGt+G2ikkPjE1PSAHmSMmH4ADyh+MAATCBKKzOz+AD5w4JCAbRqAXXjcBoQrWHM04CgkcDr6-mBq2oam1vaBzqycnqpFLW6WGoU8GAA6G40IFiD6bqbCCGq59Z6e3ANjgHo-jAAKpgSarJotOqEQhWJj-QEAIgCBAQAjgkI0lGasAoZGgdSQUAAFnoYES4AA3fxwCJkBAAG38iSsMF0MAQcAgEH4kKgIHgRnxHMIzz0VwRxwEQhEsSQgzA3RGVBuVzuXHiMm8OABMAAKkSkO1DTBzBx+LhQJAQIyrvSQAwqA1VlRTERSJRTHIYKYAF56FxcdUW8AQa38W32x0rYAu5SqNiemAABkD421gICoj0MMI8HaYPmPJYupsfm9Oj0phgxrAIFgnIgSAYCu0jIi-MSrrYHAYplwOstoZtdodTpjXZIykTKaDOCAA) without resorting to `@ts-expect-error`?

Imagine we're defining a remote API...

```js
const api = {
  str2num(_arg: string) { return 42; },
  num2str(_arg: number) { return 'forty-two'; },
};

type API = typeof api;
type APIFuncName = keyof API;
type Func<FN extends APIFuncName> = API[FN];

export function exec<FN extends APIFuncName>(
  name: FN,
  ...args: Parameters<Func<FN>>
) {
  // Unexpected error:
  // "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."
  return api[name](...args);
}

// This is fine
console.log(exec('str2num', 'zero'));
console.log(exec('num2str', 0));

// An error as expected: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
// console.log(exec('str2num', 0));
```

We're able to use the `exec(...)` function just fine, however TypeScript complains unexpectedly about the implementation of `exec(...)`.

I think the problem is that TypeScript can't associate the type of `args` with the parameters to `api[name]`.

The error message is somewhat confusing ("A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.") because `args` clearly has a tuple type already.

How can I type this correctly without resorting to @ts-expect-error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to this, but it's a bit of a hack; basically you can write a helper function to do the actual function call, where the function is typed to accept the arguments as a rest parameter. This satisfies the *"... or be passed to a rest parameter"* part of the error message. I'm not sure if there is an elegant solution.

```
export function exec<FN extends APIFuncName>(
  name: FN,
  ...args: Parameters<Func<FN>>
) {
  return callHelper(api[name], args);
}

function callHelper<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  f: F,
  args: Parameters<F>
): ReturnType<F> {
  return f(...args);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYwLwwN4FgBQMbQBOATGAK4C2AFAPpyEDmAXAVIUmAwJSYyECmUMoTAwALMQDcMAL4AaXPnIViRWvWYxlAI36EeGPoOGiA5ADMQhKAE8AtFADuIU9Pm4Zk3LlsJ+MAEEABQBJNBhffhBzeGQvHEjA0IAxMjBgADk4Cn90AGt+G2ikkPjE1PSAHmSMmH4ADyh+MAATCBKKzOz+AD5w4JCAbRqAXXjcBoQrWHM04CgkcDr6-mBq2oam1vaBzqycnqpFLW6WGoU8GAA6G40IFiD6bqbCCGq59Z6e3ANjgSERDBgHAADYggAS-BBfkIVEQSEGYG6Izk8EYEC48Rk3hws3SCyWwLBkOhemqyy2bRgVBuVzuLDgYBsgxGPFQfUZNkOx3MZwu+HpMEehGeejeyW+OC4LAASsYRAAVGx+ap9bCXf4mGDmGm3dGYjw4gD0RpgCoAFkh2lbtRx+LhQJAQCD+FcQSAGFQGqsqKYiKRKKZUaYAF56FxcA04R0QZ2u92e73AX3KVRsIMwAAMkfGOBNgVEekIVng7UmqyaLRYSr8MFMOj0phgNrAIFgcAgECQDCR2hdERAEWV-j9bA4DFMuHzMbjbo9XpWydHJGUGezUaAA)

Comment: Thanks! That's less messy than my best workaround which was to `switch (name)` and then repeat the exact same `api[name](...args)` code in each case block. For reasons that I don't understand that satisfies the other side of the error message "... A spread argument must either have a tuple type". I would love to see a fix that didn't involve changing the JavaScript

Comment: I suspect it satisfies the "must have a tuple type" part because in each case of the switch statement you have a tuple type, rather than (effectively) a union of tuple types. The only fix I could find that didn't change the Javascript was to use a type assertion, which you might consider is safe enough for a simple function like this.

Comment: If you have time - I'd love to see the type assertion fix to this. I couldn't find one.

Comment: Oh, sure - the simplest one is `(api[name] as Function)(...args)`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought you had a way to use type assertions to connect the 2 parts. Still that's better than @ts-expect-error. Thanks for the help!